# Binary search running time upper bound: Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I am trying to understand a proof that a typical binary search algorithm has a running time O(log n). In this proof, a general run time function T(n) for some input size n is determined, and this is used to show the big-O. I understand most of it, but not one of the first steps.

The proof first establishes that run time is constant if n=0, and that otherwise `T(n) <= c + T(floor(n/2))` for some constant c. This makes sense to me. The proof then explains that the function T(n) is non-decreasing, which also makes sense to me.

But then it attempts to find an upper bound that satisfies both inequalities (for n = 0 and n != 0). It does this by using the fact that T(n) is non-decreasing to establish that T(n) <= T(2<sup>ceil(log n)</sup>). This is the part that I do not understand. Where does this bound come from? Why would that particular inequality be picked? I cannot see where it originates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have that:

- n = 2^log(n)
- log n <= ceil(log n)
- 2^(log n) <= 2^(ceil(log n))

we can conclude that T(n) = T(2^(log n)) <=  T(2^(ceil(log n))) using the fact that T is  non-decreasing.